# Class not found with SWC compiled with FlexMojos and Maven

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flexmojos

Here is my virtual project setup:

1. A swc library what is using Open Source Media Framework (OSMF). This
   library is installed as a Maven artifact with FlexMojos.
2. A main application that is compiled as swf and using the library with OSMF as a Maven dependency.
3. The project is compiled fine but when I try to open the resulting .swf the Flash Player throws an exception saying that one of OSMF classes is missing (org.osmf.media.PluginInfo class not found).

Decompilation of both swc and swf showed that PluginInfo is not there.

staticLinkRuntimeSharedLibraries does not help.

Is it possible to force libraries classes include in this setup with Mojos and Maven?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Maven FlexMojo, but with Ant you need to specify the include-classes attribute to force the classes into the built library.

The flexmojo:compile-swc goal has the includeClasses parameter.  I'm betting that's what you need to include.